# Virtual Instrument App Recording Functionality With RemoteIO

Tags: ios, openal, recording, audiounit

I'm developing a virtual instrument app for iOS and am trying to implement a recording function so that the app can record and playback the music the user makes with the instrument. I'm currently using the CocosDenshion sound engine (with a few of my own hacks involving fades etc) which is based on OpenAL. From my research on the net it seems I have two options:

1. Keep a record of the user's inputs (ie. which notes were played at what volume) so that the app can recreate the sound (but this cannot be shared/emailed).
2. Hack my own low-level sound engine using AudioUnits & specifically RemoteIO so that I manually mix all the sounds and populate the final output buffer by hand and hence can save said buffer to a file. This will be able to be shared by email etc.

I have implemented a RemoteIO callback for rendering the output buffer in the hope that it would give me previously played data in the buffer but alas the buffer is always all 00.

So my question is: is there an easier way to sniff/listen to what my app is sending to the speakers than my option 2 above?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use remoteIO, I had a similar project several months ago and wanted to avoid remoteIO and audio units as much as possible, but in the end, after I wrote tons of code and read lots of documentations from third party libraries (including cocosdenshion) I end up using audio units anyway. More than that, it's not that hard to set up and work with. If you however look for a library to do most of the work for you, you should look for one written a top of core audio not open al.

Comment: Ok thanks! Looks like it's remoteio if I want to save audio output then.

Comment: Glad to help, that project I talked about took forever because I tried to avoid remoteIO, sound is difficult to work with and it's very good to have full control and  low latency.

Comment: Do either of you have a code sample I old use to get started with a similar need to capture an apps audio output and write it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [AudioCopy framework](http://www.sonomawireworks.com/iphone/audiocopy/). It does a lot of what you seem to be looking for, and will save you from potentially reinventing some wheels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've had a look at AudioCopy and it seems it needs a source file for it to work, it can't just sniff the app's audio output (unless i've misunderstood how it works).